# Add additional items to Gradle build VM classpath

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following situation:

- running IntellIJ with a custom developed plugin
- opening a Gradle project freshly
- the custom plugin requires the VM executing the build process to have certain elements in it's classpaths
- additionally the IntellIJ project needs to have elements in it's classpath, which is set up using Project Structure settings

I can get this working in Ant using Remote Debugging, `<path>` and `<pathelement>` and it works just fine.

I expected this to work in Gradle using the `org.gradle.jvmargs=-classpath abc.jar;def.jar` (and so forth) in the projects `gradle.properties` file. However, this does not seem to inject the necessary libraries to the VM executing the task. Next I tried using `JAVA_OPTS` with the same set of arguments, as according to the Gradle documentation, this will set VM options for the client VM. Indeed I set both client VM and build VM without any sign of success.

Let me rephrase. How on earth do I tell Gradle to do what any other build tool does? Take JVM args, pass them to the process that executes the task?

Comment: I assume your "custom developed plugin" is a Gradle plugin (and not, for instance, an IntelliJ plugin). Did you create it as a separate project, in the buildSrc directory, or directly as part of the main project build files? Also, are you familiar with [declaring dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html)?

Comment: Hey there. This is a IntellIJ plugin, and not a Gradle plugin. How it works is quite simple: on VM suspension, execute a bit of code to export the state of the client VM (a network visualization). This dump is imported by the IDE, and a visualization is shown. For this to work, it needs custom code in both VM's (IntellIJ and Gradle)

Comment: I see. If you need to connect to the actual Gradle process to export its state, and not a running client application, you can configure each such Gradle project through the [buildscript](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies) method. This allows you to declare external dependencies for the Gradle system classpath - both from a Maven repository or from local jar files.